# Building single model in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

What is the correct way to define model and routing to build a model that can be used as Application Data.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("main", {path:"/"});
});

App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return App.Main.find();
    }
});

App.Main = DS.Model.extend({
    appName:DS.attr('string')
});


App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    namespace: 'api/v1'
  })
});
```

This eventually invokes `api/v1/mains`. But I want it to invoke `api/v1/main` that returns the Application Data  which is a single object like

```
{
    "appName":"MyApp",
    "lastLogin": "Sat May 11 2013 11:20:03 GMT+0530",
    ...
}
```

I know about configuring plurals, but believe that is not the right way to do it. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: When configuring Plurals it is not rendering template

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("main", {path:"/"});
});

App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return App.Main.find();
    }
});


DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
  main: "main"
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    namespace: 'api/v1'
  })
});

App.Main = DS.Model.extend({
    "appName":DS.attr('string')
});
```

json received from server

```
{
    "main": {
        "app_name": "My App"
    }
}
```

template :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main">
    This is {{appName}}
</script>
```

Comment: IMO configuring plurals is the way to go...

Comment: I tried but it is not rendering the template

Comment: how did you setup the plurals? can you add more info to the question?

Comment: please see the undated question

Comment: getting the error : "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key appName but you have no mapping for it "

Comment: ok, your problem is the format of your json... please see here how ember-data expects the json to be to work correctly http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/ your json needs to specify a root that maps to your model

Comment: Now the error is not coming, but still it is not rendering

Comment: how have you called your template?

Comment: template is named "main" and it is working if I hard code json in `MainRoute` instead of `App.Main.find()` . When I do that `controller.model` is shown as object in log. But when I give `App.Main.find()` `controller.model` is `DS.recordArray` and template is not rendered.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, can you show your template?

Comment: try to change `this.resource("main", {path:"/"});` to `this.route("main", {path:"/"});` any difference?

Comment: it is the same. What I understand from this link http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/generated-objects/#toc_generated-controllers  is that `find` returns array which results in a generated ArrayController.

Comment: ok, then specify the Controller type you want with `App.MainController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({})` this should pick up your controller...

Comment: That didn't work, but could solve it by modifying `find` call.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original issue lies in the fact that you invoke `App.Main.find()` which will automatically lead to the creating of an `Ember.Arraycontroller` for the `content` of you `MainController` (generated automatically because of your routing naming). This also invokes requesting the pluralized version of you model.

So, by modifying your plurals to point to /main, you will retrieve the info, as you show, but it is still rendered inside an `Ember.ArrayController`. So to view this, you template needs to run it through an `{{#each}}`. So it probably would have worked if you had templated it:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main">
  {{#each main}}
    This is {{appName}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Your solution, identifying an individual record by parsing the key in `find()`, is correct, as that (as you already correctly stated) invokes the creation of a singleton (`Ember.ObjectController`) which can then be directly interrogated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the right approach, but solved this by invoking

```
App.Main.find("data");
```

and defining a route  `/api/v1/main/data` on server side.

As a result `App.Main.find("data");` works like fetching single record from a list of records and an `ObjectController` is generated for `main`